# "verbatim" function

Tags: function, r

this might look like a simple and basic question.
I've been studying r for a couple of months now and it seems I cannot find a function I'm looking for. I don't even know how to search it up.... out of search strings ideas.

I know there is a function to get the definition of a variable more than its contents. I explain myself...

```
> x <- c(4:6,5:9)
> x  # This will return the contents of x...  4,5,6,5,6,7,8,9.

> the.function.i.m.looking.for(x)  # would return:
> c(4:6,5:9)
```

Anyone remember that function?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dput` is what you are afer. From the help page: "Writes an ASCII text representation of an R object to a file or connection, or uses one to recreate the object."

```
> x <- c(4:6,5:9)
dput(x)
c(4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L)

> x2 <-  c(4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L)
> all.equal(x, x2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: +1 Three identical answers at the same time! Isn't @fioghual a luck interneter

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers, and YES, I do feel lucky. =)

Answer (score 4):

`dput(x)` gets you close:

```
R> dput(x)
c(4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L)
```

Or, if a character representation will suffice, then the `deparse(substitute())` idiom might be sufficient:

```
foo <- function(x) {
    deparse(substitute(x))
}
```

but you need to call it like this:

```
R> foo(c(4:6,5:9))
[1] "c(4:6, 5:9)"
```

not this

```
R> foo(x)
[1] "x"
```

Comment: @baptiste Nice! I knew there was a way to get that output but couldn't remember the correct incantation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return the syntax that you need to recreate the object then `dput()` is your friend:

```
x <- c(4:6,5:9)
dput(x)
c(4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L)
```

Comment: +1 Three identical answers at the same time. Isn't @fioghual a luck interneter